# Bloom only colors with at least one value equal to 1,

Tags: glsl

I want to bloom/blur any color that has a 1 in it,

like (1,0,0) and (1,0,1) etc.

The script bellow blooms any color over a threshold,
but what I want blooms only specific colors.

'Selective bloom'

```
uniform sampler2D bgl_RenderedTexture;
const float BRIGHT_PASS_THRESHOLD = 0.55;
const float BRIGHT_PASS_OFFSET = 0.08;

#define blurclamp 0.002
#define bias 10.8
#define KERNEL_SIZE 6.0

vec2 texcoord = vec2(gl_TexCoord[0]).st;

vec4 bright(vec2 coo)
{
  vec4 color = texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, coo);
  color = max(color - BRIGHT_PASS_THRESHOLD, 0.0);
  return color / (color + BRIGHT_PASS_OFFSET);   
}

void main(void)
{
  vec2 blur = vec2(clamp( bias, -blurclamp, blurclamp ));

  vec4 col = vec4( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
  for ( float x = -KERNEL_SIZE + 1.0; x < KERNEL_SIZE; x += 1.0 )
  {
    for ( float y = -KERNEL_SIZE + 1.0; y < KERNEL_SIZE; y += 1.0 )
    {
      col += bright( texcoord + vec2( blur.x * x, blur.y * y ) );
    }
  }
  col /= ((KERNEL_SIZE+KERNEL_SIZE)-1.0)*((KERNEL_SIZE+KERNEL_SIZE)-1.0);
  gl_FragColor = col + texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, texcoord);
}
```

is the script I was trying to edit, but I don't know GLSL (I know python)

Comment: Can you show us an image of the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: basically just like normal bloom, but only colors with a 1 in them, (shadeless) so full red, full blue, full green all bloom, but a specular reflection will not bloom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking. When you say "only colors with a 1 in them", are you including colors that have other values but also have a 1 in them? For example, do you want to include a color such as (1.0, 0.5, 0.25)? If so, you can do something like this:

```
vec4 bright(vec2 coo)
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, coo);
    float max = max(max(color.r, color.g), color.b);
    if (max >= 1.0)
    {
        max = 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        max = 0.0;
    }
    color = color * max;
    return color;
}
```

If you only want colors where the values are exactly 0 or 1, then you need to do some more work. Something like:

```
vec4 bright(vec2 coo)
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, coo);
    bool threshMult = 0.0;
    if (((color.r == 1.0) || (color.r == 0.0)) &&
        ((color.g == 1.0) || (color.g == 0.0)) &&
        ((color.b == 1.0) || (color.b == 0.0)))
    {
        meetsThreshold = max(max(color.r, color.g), color.b);
    }

    color = color * threshMult;
    return color;
}
```